# Mi método de deposito no me modifica la variable saldo

Tags: c++

Tengo un saldo inicial de 2500 en el programa pero cuando hago un deposito en el programa y luego paso a consultar el saldo este me regresa el saldo inicial que es de 2500 y no el nuevo saldo. Estoy haciendo uso de un archivo header para almacenar mis clases, un archivo CPP para poner el contenido de los métodos que hay en mis clases y otro archivo CPP para el main.
Estoy seguro que el método depositar funciona ya que cuando agregue un count si me regresaba el valor del saldo pero en el método consulta no me regresa el saldo que debería se reinicia.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Clases.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        //Variables.
        int p, x;
        //Objetos.
        Cajero caja;
        Operaciones op;
        //Inicio del programa.
        do
        {
            //Menu.
            cout << "Bienvenido" << endl;
            cout << "Escoja una opcion." << endl;
            cout << "1.-Consulta de saldo." << endl;
            cout << "2.-Consulta de movimientos." << endl;
            cout << "3.-Realizar un deposito." << endl;
            cout << "4.-Realizar un retiro" << endl;
            cout << "5.-Pedir un prestamo" << endl;
            cout << "6.-Salir" << endl;
            cin >> x;

            switch (x)
            {
            case 1:
                //Consulta de saldo.
                caja.consultar();
                break;
            case 2:
                //Consulta de movimientos.
                caja.consultarmov();
                break;
            case 3:
                //Realizar un deposito.
                op.depositar(caja);
                break;
            case 4:
                //Realizar un retiro.
                op.retirar(caja);
                break;
            case 5:
                //Pedir un prestamo.
                prestamo(caja);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }


            cout << "Desea realizar otra accion." << endl;
            cout << "1.-Si." << endl;
            cout << "2.-No." << endl;
            cin >> p;
        } while (p == 1);
        cout << "Hasta luego.";
    }
    #include <iostream>
#include "Clases.h"

using namespace std;

//Constructores.
Cajero::Cajero()
{
    saldo = 2500;
    dep = 0;
    ret = 0;
    pos = 0;
    pres = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        movn[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        mov[i] = 0;
    }

}

Operaciones::Operaciones(){}

//Metodos de clase Cajero.
void Cajero::consultar()
{
    cout << "El saldo de su cuenta es de " << saldo << " Pesos" << endl;


}

void Cajero::consultarmov()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
    {
        switch (mov[i])
        {
        case 1: cout << i + 1 << "-" << "Retiro " << ": ";
            break;
        case 2: cout << i + 1 << "-" << "Deposito " << ": ";
            break;
        case 3: cout << i + 1 << "-" << "Prestamo " << ": ";
            break;
        }
        cout << movn[i] << endl;
    }


}

//Metodos de clase Operaciones.
void Operaciones::retirar(Cajero caja)
{
    do
    {
        cout << "¿Cuanto dinero desea retirar?" << endl;
        cin >> caja.ret;

        if (caja.saldo - caja.ret < 0)
        {
            cout << "No puede retirar mas dinero del que tiene en su cuenta" << endl;
        }
    } while (caja.saldo - caja.ret < 0);

    caja.saldo = caja.saldo - caja.ret;
    caja.mov[caja.pos] = 1;
    caja.movn[caja.pos] = caja.ret;
    caja.pos++;
}

void Operaciones::depositar(Cajero caja)
{
    cout << "¿Cuanto dinero desea depositar?" << endl;
    cin >> caja.dep;

    caja.saldo = caja.saldo + caja.dep;

    caja.mov[caja.pos] = 2;
    caja.movn[caja.pos] = caja.dep;
    caja.pos++;
    cout << caja.saldo<<endl;
}
//Metodo amigo.
void prestamo(Cajero caja)
{
    cout << "Las opciones de prestamo son las siguientes:" << endl << "10,000 pesos" << endl << "25,000" << endl << "50,000" << endl << "75,000" << endl << "100,000" << endl;
    cin >> caja.pres;
    caja.saldo = caja.saldo + caja.pres;

    caja.mov[caja.pos] = 3;
    caja.movn[caja.pos] = caja.pres;
    caja.pos++;
}

    #ifndef CLASES_H
#define CLASES_H


//Clases.
class Cajero
{
private:
    //Variables.
    int pos;
    double saldo, movn[100], dep, ret, pres;
    char mov[100];
public:
    //Constructor.
    Cajero();

    //Metodos.
    void consultar();
    void consultarmov();
    //void consultar();
    //void consultarmov();
    //void prestamo();

    //Metodos y Clases amigas.
    friend void prestamo(Cajero caja);
    friend class Operaciones;

};

class Operaciones {
public:
    //Constructor.
    Operaciones();

    //Metodos.
    void retirar(Cajero caja);
    void depositar(Cajero caja);
};
#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternativamente a lo propuesto en la otra respuesta, también puedes usar referencias:

```
Cajero caja;
void Operaciones::depositar(Cajero & caja)
//                                 ^ referencia
{
    cout << "¿Cuanto dinero desea depositar?" << endl;
    cin >> caja.dep;

    caja.saldo = caja.saldo + caja.dep;

    caja.mov[caja.pos] = 2;
    caja.movn[caja.pos] = caja.dep;
    caja.pos++;
    cout << caja.saldo<<endl;
}
```

De esta forma también evitas crear una copia del objeto `Cajero`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, el de agregar la referencia fue mas que suficiente para arreglar el problema sin modificar los metodos.
solo una duda y que diferencia hay en agregar la '&'? que me esta diciendo el '&', tengo la idea pero me gustaria estar seguro

Comment: @AndresMauricioMayOlguin El `&` sirve para declarar referencias. Sin ese símbolo, usarás una variable por valor, como te comentaron en la otra respuesta... pero al añadirlo pasas a usar una referencia, que es una especie de puntero implícito a la variable original.

Comment: @AndresMauricioMayOlguin por cierto, si una de las dos respuestas soluciona tu problema márcala como solución. No tienes por qué marcar necesariamente mi respuesta sino aquella que mejor solucione tu problema.

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema es porque estas pasando el objeto caja como como copia de valores. Lo que ocurre es que al hacer

```
op.depositar(caja);
```

Estas pasando una copia del objeto caja. Dentro del método depositar, se modifica el valor del saldo de la copia de la caja, copia que se destruye cuando el método finaliza.
Lo que debes hacer, es pasar una referencia al objeto caja.
Necesitas crear un puntero que apunte a un nuevo objeto Cajero, el cual puedes pasar. Tu codigo (para ese método quedaría algo asi, pongo partes que van separadas juntas)

```
Cajero *caja = new Caja();
void Operaciones::depositar(Cajero *caja)
{
    cout << "¿Cuanto dinero desea depositar?" << endl;
    cin >> caja->dep;

    caja->saldo = caja->saldo + caja->dep;

    caja->mov[caja->pos] = 2;
    caja->movn[caja->pos] = caja->dep;
    caja->pos++;
    cout << caja->saldo<<endl;
}
```

De esta forma, los cambios realizados se ejecutarán sobre el objeto creado, del cual hemos pasado su dirección mediante el puntero creado.
Si tienes dudas, no dudes en preguntar.